# addiing onclick event inside link with javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to add onclickevent inside link so the link would look like this.

```
<a href="/" onclick="parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();" target="_parent">mylink</a>
```

Using this code does not work

```
element.addEventListener('click', parent.$.fn.colorbox.close(), false);
```

this is full code

```
window.onload = function(){
  var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (var i=0; i<anchors.length; i++){
    anchors[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    anchors[i].addEventListener('click', xxx, false); 
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: And where is `element` defined?

Comment: @NewToJS I added full code. I try to alter all links on page

Comment: `anchors[i].addEventListener('click', xxx, false);` will call the function `xxx` so this should work. I'm having trouble understanding what it is you're having an issue with.... You could use `anchors[i].setAttribute('onclick', 'parent.$.fn.colorbox.close');` assuming `parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();` does something.

Comment: @NewToJS hi, setAttribute adds onclick inside link, but I wanted to avoid it sinde I have read that not all browsers handle it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an anchor tag `<a href=".....">`, you should to attach the event using javascript and **prevent the default behavior** of the anchor tag by using `preventDefault()`.

For example:

```
function yourFunction(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // <---- this is important
   e.target.parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
}
element.addEventListener('click', yourFunction, false);
```

Comment: Hi, after adding exactly what you wrote, there is still no onclick attribute inside <a>. target=_blank is set without problems.

Comment: If you add it with javascript there isn't going to be an onclick attribute that you can see, but it will just work when you click it since you added it programmatically.

Comment: Try opening chrome (or firefox) debugger and set a breakpoint in the onclick function you are attaching.

Comment: After clicking on links I get error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$' of undefined in console on this line "e.target.parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();" Strange that if I add onclick event using setAttribute, everything works.